# Как сделать, чтобы 2 скрипта срабатывали одновременно при одном клике мыши

Tags: javascript, jquery

Приветствую смотрящих.

Есть задумка сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку один блок скрывался и на его месте появлялся другой. Для этого использую 2 скрипта(прикрепил ниже). Но проблема в том, что они срабатывают не одновременно, а по очереди. То есть: нажимаю один раз на кнопку — появляется новый блок, нажимаю второй раз — старый блок исчезает.

Нужно, чтобы все это происходило в одно нажатие. Может нужно как-то объединить 2 скрипта в 1, но я не программист, поэтому не знаю как это сделать и возможно ли это вообще.

Скрипты, которые использую:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').on('click', '.div1', function(){
    $(this).hide();
 });
});
```

```
function viewDiv(){
  document.getElementById("div2").style.display = "block";
};
```

Comment: а позвать функу viewDiv сразу после хайда, пробовали ?

Comment: После `$(this).hide();`... в общем случае добавить `viewDiv();` — вызов функции. А конкретно здесь легче выкинуть функцию и после hide добавить `$('#div2').show();`

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME Большое спасибо, помогло)